# Background music in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, plugins, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to add background music on my flutter app . I installed the audioplayer plugin but am unable to set a background music which runs on loop and i also want to pause it too . Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check this [code](https://gist.github.com/MarkOSullivan94/616d2a3bbd4a8d9c9d79771808fdc30c) which uses the [assets_audio_player](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player) package.

You can use the `initState` function to play the music on a loop.

Comment: any way to pause it?

Comment: You can add a button and use `assetsAudioPlayer.pause();` onPressed

Comment: i am getting this error , AssetsAudio is not defined for this type _MyAppState

Comment: Did you add `assets_audio_player: ^2.0.7+9` in your `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Add `_` in front of assetsAudioPlayer.pause();

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a background music for your app (not an audio player) then check out

Flutter Flame Engine

https://flame-engine.org/

apart for 2D gaming engine, it also gives you ability to play background music (configurable) and short sounds for taps.